# Waking computer with raspberry pi zero usb keyboard gadget

Tags: pi-zero-w, gadget

I've been trying to set up a raspberry pi zero as a keyboard gadget, hoping i could wake a laptop (No ethernet) with it. I would also be able to encrypt it and send the password, which is an added bonus.

I've gotten the keyboard gadget to work, and I've set echo 0xa0 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes to enable remote wakeup on the keyboard gadget.

Previously when the laptop was in hibernation i would get no response when sending keystrokes. Now i get:

-bash: echo: write error: Resource temporarily unavailable

I had hoped just any key would suffice for waking the laptop, but it seems i need to specifically send a wake up event, only i have no idea how :)

Any help would be much appreciated!

If anyone else wants to give it a go, here are the sites I've used to get to this point:
https://www.isticktoit.net/?p=1383
https://usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/hut1_12v2.pdf
https://www.rmedgar.com/blog/using-rpi-zero-as-keyboard-setup-and-device-definition

Comment: are you able to wake the laptop with a regular usb keyboard?

Comment: Would've added this as a comment (need 50 reputation to do so), and it seems my question has not been linked to my account. Strange. <br/>
Yes, i am able to wake the laptop with a usb keyboard it can be enabled in the bios. Since just any key from a regular usb keyboard will wake the laptop i had hoped the same thing would apply to the pi zero :)

Comment: do not put additional information into an answer .... edit your question instead .... then delete this answer

Comment: found this .... it mentions the `remote wakeup` bit in the device descriptor

Comment: I know, but i created the question as a guest so i can't edit it :/

Comment: The remote wakeup should be set by the echo 0xa0 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes already. I think i only need to know how to send a resume packet

Comment: google `usb keyboard device descriptor remote wakeup bit` ... a lot of info comes up

Comment: try emulating a mouse instead .... maybe the wakeup process is different from the keyboard

Comment: Did you get any further with this? I have been trying to do the same thing.